# how to store nodejs express session data using rest api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

how to store the session data using api

my app layer no connected with Da layer i am consuming data from api how to manage app layer session data with data base mongodb rest api

thanks in advance

Comment: i don't have database in my app layer i am getting data from api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use JSON web token (jwt) `http://jwt.io/`

You can get session data everywhere.
With JWT you are protected from CSRF attacks.
JWT have strict standart and support many popular languages.